# Mysql query, WP custom fields

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to select some things from few WP tables, one of which is custom field value with a certain key. Problem is, some of posts don't have custom field with this key but aside of that they match query. So question is, how do I select even posts that doesn't have custom field with this key, but other than that match query? Value of field for the posts that do not have custom field should be set 0. I figured it's something like COALESCE, but I'm either using it wrong or it can't be used in this case. My query so far is:

```
select lists.id,lists.`type`,lists.`status`,lists.watched_eps, lists.score,wp_posts.post_title,wp_posts.post_name,wp_terms.slug,wp_postmeta.meta_value from anime_lists
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON (wp_posts.ID = lists.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_postmeta.post_id= lists.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON(wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON(wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id)
where lists.id=1
and wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
and wp_postmeta.meta_key='eps'
group by lists.`post_id`
order by lists.`status`, wp_posts.post_title
```

As it is, query outputs everything that I need but without these posts that do not have custom field 'eps'. If I remove `and wp_postmeta.meta_key='eps'` it outputs these posts, but that way I get wrong value in `wp_postmeta.meta_value` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand what you want, you can just change your wp_postmeta join to a `LEFT JOIN` and move the `WHERE` condition on that table to the join, leaving;

```
SELECT lists.id, lists.`type`, lists.`status`, lists.watched_eps, 
       lists.score,wp_posts.post_title,wp_posts.post_name,wp_terms.slug,
       wp_postmeta.meta_value 
FROM anime_lists
INNER JOIN wp_posts 
  ON wp_posts.ID = anime_lists.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta 
  ON wp_postmeta.post_id = anime_lists.post_id 
 AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='eps'
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
  ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
  ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms 
  ON(wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id)
WHERE lists.id=1
  AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
GROUP BY lists.`post_id`
ORDER BY lists.`status`, wp_posts.post_title
```

Comment: Seems that have done the trick. Changed `wp_postmeta.meta_value` to COALESCE(wp_postmeta.meta_value, 0) and it seems to do what I need. Thanks a lot.